# Issue with Opencart 3 Checkout page last Confirm Step

Tags: opencart, opencart-3

I need help regarding this below issue:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: Error: Could not load template /www/hosting/part2print.cz/eshop/catalog/view/theme/default/template/checkout/payment_manager/confirm.tpl! in /www/hosting/part2print.cz/eshop/system/storage/modification/system/library/template/template.php:23 Stack trace: #0 /www/hosting/part2print.cz/eshop/system/storage/modification/system/library/template.php(57): Template\Template->render() #1 /www/hosting/part2print.cz/eshop/system/storage/modification/system/engine/loader.php(128): Template->render() #2 /www/hosting/part2print.cz/eshop/system/ocmodify/classes/engine/override.php(8): Loader->view() #3 /www/hosting/part2print.cz/eshop/system/ocmodify/classes/override/loader.php(55): OCMOverride->__call() #4 /www/hosting/part2print.cz/eshop/system/ocmodify/classes/engine/bridge.php(47): OCMLoader->view() #5 /www/hosting/part2print.cz/eshop/system/ocmodify/classes/library/load.php(82): OCMBridge->__call() #6 /www/hosting/part2print.cz/eshop/system/ocmodify/classes/engine/controller.php(121): OCMLoad->view in /www/hosting/part2print.cz/eshop/system/storage/modification/system/library/template/template.php on line 23
```

As I am using Opencart Version 3.0.3.1, when I go through checkout and reach to the 2nd last step "Payment Method" and select a method and click Continue, it gives me this above error (this error comes for some of method, like cash on delivery but not for all - This page (..catalog/view/theme/default/template/checkout/payment_manager/confirm.tpl!) is not even available, but Yes checkout/payment_manager folder is available).

One thing I want to clear, that I didn't changed the Payment Method controller file code and neither of confirm.twig file code, its a default opencart code. But this behaving strange.

Anybody of you can help please!!

Comment: Seems you use not OC3.0.x.x module because `confirm.tpl`. Template file in OC3 must be `confirm.twig`.

Comment: @K.B., Yes, off course, I am using OC 3.0.3.1 and I have only confirm.twig file in project only. No tpl files available.

Comment: what about your posted error?: `this error comes for some of method, like cash on delivery but not for all - This page (..catalog/view/theme/default/template/checkout/payment_manager/confirm.tpl!` There i see confirm.tpl... where from this file?

Comment: @K.B. This what I am saying, that checkout/payment_manager folder exists, but confirm.tpl is not available (as this folder used by another payment method).
while COD is OC default Payment method, so it shouldn't need to go to this path -> checkout/payment_manager, instead it needs load default confirm.twig file.

Answer (score 0):

As already said, OpenCart from version 3.x on use .twig only and not .tpl as template file extension.
And your message says it already all: you are using an additional extension which tries to load the template **payment_manager/confirm.tpl**

So, either you are using beside this extension also another one which allows .tpl files (not recommended!), or your extension is not for OC 3.x

btw: the path **template/checkout/payment_manager** shows me, that that extension does not follow the standard.
And, why are you using OC 3.0.3.1 and not 3.0.3.2 (which is better because of several bugfixes)?